# TextInputEditText loses focus after it gets it after request

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, material-components

**Current status:**
I have an outer fragment with `ViewPager2` that has shows a nested fragment that contains the `TextInputLayout` that I want to be focused whenever I open the page, with contents of the `TextInputLayout` selected.
Right now I request focus in `onResume`, it is granted but then lost (see the log below)

```
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onAttach
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onCreateView
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onResume
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onCreateView quan focus:true current:focus view:com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{2c195d VFED..CL. .F....I. 0,0-0,0 #7f08019d app:id/quantity}
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onResume given focus
D/DocumentItemDetailFragm: onCreateView quan focus:false current:focus view:null
```

My `TextInputLayout`

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/quantity"
                        style="@style/CustomEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="@string/document_item_quantity"
                        android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
                        android:minEms="4"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        tools:text="0.0" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My fragment relevant code:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
...
        with(binding.quantity) {
            setOnClickListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView quan clicked")
                this.selectAll()
            }
            onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView quan focus:$hasFocus current:${logFocus(mainActivity)}")
                if (!hasFocus && "${this.text}" != "") viewModel.updateQuantity("${this.text ?: 0}")
                else this.selectAll()
            }
        }
    }
...

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume")
        super.onResume()
        if (binding.quantity.requestFocus()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume given focus")
            binding.quantity.selectAll()
            showHideKeyboard(mainActivity, false)
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be consistent with this issue:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/500, specifically the user `jadroa`'s comment

> This is still happening when com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout used inside viewpager2 based on recyclerview.

**What I've tried:**
based on the suggestions in the issue, I changed the dependencies to:

```
'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'
'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

which didn't help (same with newer versions)

I also tried to apply the fix posted by user `slavonnet` 
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/500#issuecomment-635933214, basically:

```
val a: TextInputLayout = view.parent.parent as TextInputLayout
    if (a.editText?.imeOptions != IME_ACTION_NEXT && a.editText?.isSingleLine == true)
        a.editText?.imeOptions = IME_ACTION_NEXT
    if (a.focusSearch(view, ViewGroup.FOCUS_FORWARD).id == -1)
        a.focusSearch(view, ViewGroup.FOCUS_FORWARD).id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
    a.editText?.nextFocusForwardId = a.focusSearch(view, ViewGroup.FOCUS_FORWARD).id
```

but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my scenario, I am lost at figuring out what exactly `view` is in this snippet. I've tried putting it in the `OnFocusChangeListener` of the `TextInputEditText` (so view is the TextInputEditText), but it didn't work
I refer to the `TextInputLayout` using binding, and I really don't understand how it can be related to some view as parent.parent

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve what I want, or on how to implement the `slavonnet`'s solution